# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string issue

Tags: perl

I know that this is very common problem while doing Perl scripts, but I cannot find the solution, and probably it's very simple.

I've two folders inside my data folder: BWA_1 and BWA_2. I want to print the filename with the full path, of a certain file that is inside these folder. To do that, I have this lines inside the script.

```
my $rpath="/home/seq4/Desktop/data/";

for ( my $i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {
    my $BWA_dir = $rpath . "BWA_" . $i;
    print "$BWA_dir\n";
    my $bam_file = glob("$BWA_dir/*SNP.bam");
    print "$bam_file\n";
}
```

When I execute it:

```
/home/seq4/Desktop/data/BWA_1
/home/seq4/Desktop/data/BWA_1/subset_fusa.SNP.bam
/home/seq4/Desktop/data/
Use of uninitialized value $bam_file in concatenation (.) or string at sc.pl line 17.
```

How can I fix this problem?

The file exists. If I change this line:

```
my $bam_file = glob("$BWA_dir/*SNP.bam");
```

With this (both files have the same name):

```
my $bam_file = $BWA_dir . "/subset_fusa.SNP.bam";
```

Output:

```
    /home/seq4/Desktop/data/BWA_1
    /home/seq4/Desktop/data/BWA_1/subset_fusa.SNP.bam
    /home/seq4/Desktop/data/BWA_2
    /home/seq4/Desktop/data/BWA_2/subset_fusa.SNP.bam
```

The file exists...:

```
ls -la BWA_2/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 seq4 alg89 4096 nov 17 17:16 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 seq4 alg89 4096 nov 17 17:15 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 seq4 alg89    0 nov 17 17:16 subset_fusa.SNP.bam
```

Comment: Note that `glob` will print a file name even if it doesn't match, if you do not use wildcards. Use `ls` to see your files instead.

Comment: If there is a file in BWA_2 with that name, and you have full permissions, then I think we cannot reproduce this. Perhaps tell us the output of `print glob('/home/Desktop/data/BWA_2/*SNP.bam')` as well as of `ls -la /home/Desktop/data/BWA_2`.

Comment: Your edit doesn't prove that the second file exists. You're just printing a string, you're not checking for the file's existence. What do you see if you add code like `print "$bam_file exists: ", -f $bam_file, "\n";`?

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $bam_file in concatenation (.) or string at sc.pl line 13.
Use of uninitialized value $bam_file in -f at sc.pl line 13.
Use of uninitialized value in print at sc.pl line 13.
 exists:

Comment: It seems that it does not exist.. but... why for the first file yes? I mean, I've created both files, just typing: touch BWA_1/subset_fusa.SNP.bam BWA_2/subset_fusa.SNP.bam

Comment: Unless you share the information, we cannot know why this happens. My guess would be that you are running the script from the wrong dir. You say you created the files with `touch BWA_1/...`, that you globbed `./data/BWA...` but got output `/home/data/` (not true). We can only guess as to what the real information is.

Comment: OK, sorry, I was just trying to avoid writing large path with a lot of subdirs. I'm going to modify it. Anyway, if you create manually 2 folders inside principal folder, named BWA_1 and BWA_2, and create inside of them subset_fusa.SNP.bam files, if you run my piece of code from principal folder, it works for you?

Comment: @cucurbit Yes, when I tested this, I got the same result you did. The explanation is in my answer. I asked you 50 minutes ago to confirm that your file existed, but you did not respond. If you had, you would have had your answer sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the documentation [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
glob EXPR
glob    In list context, returns a (possibly empty) list of filename
        expansions on the value of EXPR such as the standard Unix shell
        /bin/csh would do. In scalar context, glob iterates through such
        filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.
```

Note that you are using `glob` in a scalar context, which in my opinion is the wrong way to use it. In case of multiple matching files, you will only get the first. The natural way to do it would be either using list context with a for loop:

```
for my $file (glob ...) {
    print "$file\n";
}
```

Or iterate using a while loop, using scalar context:

```
while (my $file = glob ...) {
```

Note also that you can use `glob` for the whole thing:

```
my @files = glob "data/BWA_{1,2,3}/*SNP.bam";
```

(You can use `BWA_*` for short.)

**EDIT:**

I have found out the real reason your code does not work. I tried it on my system and I got the same behaviour, even though clearly the files existed.

The reason you are not getting the expected result is like I said early on that you are using `glob` in scalar context. It is iterating over the results, and after the first, it returns undef. That you changed the variable that is used inside the glob does not matter. By changing 2 characters in your code I got the desired result:

```
my $rpath = "foo/";

for ( my $i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {
    my $BWA_dir = $rpath . "BWA_" . $i;
    print "$BWA_dir\n";
    my @bam_file = glob("$BWA_dir/*SNP.bam");
    #  ^--- changed to array to impose list context
    print "@bam_file\n";
}
```

One might think that using the statement again with a new string would refresh the iterator, but that is not the case. This might be some optimization.

Comment: Thanks TLP. I know that the correct way to use glob is with an array, but, I'm sure that I have only one file with that name in the folder, that's why I'm using it. Anyway, if you know a better way to do this, I would be glad to read it. I have edited the post. You can see the complete name of the file I'm looking for.

Comment: @cucurbit When Perl says the file is not there, and you say it is, it is usually you who are wrong. And if Perl is wrong, it is your fault anyway. Your test to see if the file is indeed there is not definitive, since `glob "foo"` will return `foo` even if `foo` does not exist. Use `ls` to check if the file is there.

Comment: @cucurbit Can you confirm that the file is there by checking manually?

Comment: Could also do: `my ($bam_file) = glob("$BWA_dir/*SNP.bam");` which will also force a list context.  First element of array will be assigned, rest will be discarded.

Comment: @Sobrique Yes, that would be useful for this specific case, with just one file per dir. However, it is more correct to show all results, or this will become a very hard bug to spot in future expansions of the code.

Comment: Indeed. Pros and cons of either. Basing any code on an assumption of only being a single file seems potentially hazardous.

Comment: Now it is working... why my ($bam_file) works but my $bam_file don't? I thought it was the same. I'm learning, sorry. And many many thanks for the help :). I was becoming totally crazy.

Comment: @cucurbit The first few lines of my answer explains the difference. When you use parentheses, you impose list context on the glob. When you just use a scalar assignment, you impose scalar context. This concept if list vs scalar context is central to Perl, and you should learn it.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving this warning because `$bam_file` is undefined, because either there is no file matching `/home/Desktop/data/BWA_2/*SNP.bam`, or you do not have permission to read that folder in the first place. If you wish to prevent that warning, you can do a few things:

Change the string based on whether a file is found or not:

```
my $bam_file = glob("$BWA_dir/*SNP.bam") || ''; # If glob returns undef, make $bam_file an empty string
```

Only print if a file was found:

```
print "$bam_file\n" if (defined $bam_file);
```

Comment: I know why I'm receiving the warning... the thing is that file exists... Actually I need to store that file in the variable, not only avoid the warning.
Thanks!